# Show that a convex subset, which contains lines from the origin for everyone of its elements is a unit ball for some norm.

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a linear space and $D \subset X$ be some set.

The set D has the following properties:

(1) $D$ is convex

(2) if $x \in D$, then $ax \in D$ for every $|a| \le 1$

(3) for every $0 \ne v \in X$, $D \cap${$tv | t > 0$}$ = [0,u]$ such that $0 \ne u \in X$

I need to show that there is some norm on $X$ such that $D$ is the unit ball of $X$ with this norm.

My attempt was to define:

$||v|| = \frac{1}{Sup\{t \ge 0 | tv \in D\}}$

However, I couldn't manage to prove this norm satisfies the triangle inequality.

For $v, w \in D$, I set:

$A = \{a \ge 0 | av \in D\}$

$B = \{b \ge 0 | bw \in D\}$

$C = \{c \ge 0 | c(v+w) \in D\}$

and I need to show:

$\frac{1}{SupC} \le \frac{1}{SupA} + \frac{1}{SupB}$ which is equal to $\frac{SupASupB}{SupA + SupB} \le SupC$, but I couldn't figure how to continue from here.

Any help with this triangle inequality or wit a different idea for a definition of the norm would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the assumption that $D$ is convex to relate $C$ to $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Bad definition of $\|v\|$. Use Moikowski functional: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional

Comment: @Kavi Rama but then it will be $||v|| = 0$ for every $v$

Comment: @GabiG You probably got the definition wrong. Minkowski functional is defined by $\|v\|=\inf \{t>0
: v \in tD\}$ not $\inf \{t>0: tv \in D\}$.